# Header ribbon with css

Tags: css, html

I think I've lost my head over the past few days. Currently finalizing my site and thought I would add a fixed header ribbon at the top of my pages just to add a little aesthetics to it. The ribbon displays fine but when scrolling the pages all the content under the ribbon div seem to scroll *over* the ribbon instead of *under* the ribbon. Im not sure if I just missed something in my styling or if this is a problem with my markup.. or both :/

markup looks like the following:

```
<body onunload="" class="">
<div id="ribbon" class="ribbon"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="titleRow">
<hr />
  <div id="">
    <div id="primary"><script type="text/javascript">  
        Cufon.replace('#primary'); 
    </script><a href="">Text Placement</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="/portfolio" title="Portfolio" class="siteNav">Port</a></li>
    <li><a href="/profile" title="About" class="siteNav">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact" title="Contact" class="siteNav">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Blog" class="siteNav">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<div id="content"><hr />
    <div id="workHolder" class="tier590">
        <h2><a href="" title="View my projects" class="pageTitle siteNav">My Work</a></h2>
        <ul id="workList">
```

My css is set with position: fixed, width: 100%, height: 6px, and background-color:#000

Any help on this so that I can get things under the ribbon when scrolling would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your CSS and I'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your z index to 999.

```
#ribbon {
position: fixed;
width: 100%; 
height: 6px;
background-color:#000;
z-index:999;
}
```